# Multiple list for fetching image file from different directory

Tags: jmeter

Have different `images` in various folder categorized according to the size of the folder. And Each folder have multiple directory like `CX` and `MX` OR `VX`. Each of this `CX`/`MX`/`VX` have `SER00001`, `SER00002`, `SER00003` And each of this folder have all the images.

Use Case:

1. Select any random directory of any size, like 5MB or 30MB or 1GB
2. Each 5MB/30MB/1Gb folder have folder like `CX`, `MX` or `VX`.
3. Each `CX/MX/VX` have `SER00001/SER00002/SER00003...` folders.
4. Each `SER00001/SER00002/SER00003...` folders contain the images.
5. Based upon the selection like `all` or `single` the `CX`, `MX` or `VX` will be selected like for `all` all the `CX,VX & MX` will be selected and inside all the folder eventually the images under it. Now for single only one from `CX,VX and MX` will be selected and and all the `SER` folder and eventually the images under it

```js
import groovy.io.FileType;
def dir = new File(vars.get("dirName"));
def selectionPattern = ["All","Single"];
def list = [];
def listNew = [];
def list_series = [];
def list_images = [];
def modalityDir = [];
def modalityFileName = [];
def finalModalityName = [];
def rnd = new Random();
def rndSelect = new Random();
def userSelectionForModalityFolder = selectionPattern[rndSelect.nextInt(selectionPattern.size())];

if (userSelectionForModalityFolder === "All") {
    dir.eachDir() {
        dirList ->
        list << dirList
    }
    def randomParentDirectorySelected = list[rnd.nextInt(list.size())];
    randomParentDirectorySelected.eachDir() {
        listDir ->
        list_series << listDir
    }
    for (allSelectionDir in list_series) {
        allSelectionDir.eachDir() {
            allSelectDirectory ->
            list_images << allSelectDirectory
        }
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < list_images.size(); b++) {
        File[] modalityFiles = list_images[b].listFiles();
        modalityFileName << modalityFiles
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < modalityFileName.size(); n++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < modalityFileName[n].size(); p++) {
            finalModalityName << modalityFileName[n][p]
        }
    }
    vars.putObject("All_Modality",finalModalityName);
} else {
    dir.eachDir() {
        dirList ->
        list << dirList
    }
    def randomParentDirectorySelected = list[rnd.nextInt(list.size())]
    randomParentDirectorySelected.eachDir() {
        secDirList ->
        listNew << secDirList
    }
    if (listNew.size() > 2) {
        def totalFile = ranSelect.nextInt(listNew.size());
    } else {
        Random ranSelect = new Random();
        def totalFile = ranSelect.nextInt(listNew.size() + 4);
        def random_ModalitySelection = listNew[rnd.nextInt(listNew.size())]
        random_ModalitySelection.eachDir() {
            modalityD ->
            modalityDir << modalityD
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < modalityDir.size(); i++) {
            File[] modalityFiles = modalityDir[i].listFiles();
            modalityFileName << modalityFiles
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < modalityFileName.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < modalityFileName[j].size(); k++) {
                finalModalityName << modalityFileName[j][k]
            }
        }
        vars.putObject("All_Modality",finalModalityName);
    }

}
```

This code work fine but I have declared too many list inside my code, when I am running for large number of image file I am getting longer response in the code

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think it's a good idea to use random data because I believe tests need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) and with your approach if you detect a performance issue you will have to take extra steps to replay the test scenario
2. If generating the list is time/resource consuming you could move it to [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) to pre-generate the list of files for each virtual user and write it to the CSV file. Then in the main Thread Group you can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), it will be the fastest option and will give you the repeatability mentioned in the point 1.